# Is it possible to save Recipient List of the jenkins email-ext plugin to workspace as prop file?

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I have a with pre-configed Recipient List in the email-ext plugin.
In order to save the Recipient List of the email-ext plugin to workspace, which is hosted on remote agent, as prop file, I tried the following pre-send script

```
recipients = msg.getRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO)
rcp_list='RCP_LIST='
for(r in recipients){
    rcp_list += (r.toString() + ',')
}
File file = new File("rcp_list.prop")
file.write rcp_list
```

But I found that the plugin tries to write the file on the master machine. Does anyone has another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline DSL runs on `master` node even that your write `node('someAgentName')` in your pipeline.
Use [sh](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script) like a workaround.

```groovy
 sh("echo \"$rcp_list\" > rcp_list.prop")
```

It will print `rcp_list` in `rcp_list.prop` with `[]`. To avoid it you can do something like:

```groovy
 String listAsString = rcp_list.join(', ')
 sh("echo \"$listAsString\" > rcp_list.prop")
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I afraid that sh is not support by **email-ext** plugin's pre-send script, https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+Recipes

Comment: You can try convert it to [pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-PipelineExamples). And using [node](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-node-code-allocate-node) you can get to your remote agent